# Why is pg_restore returning successfully but not actually restoring my database? PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL 9.5 with pgAdmin 4 (I would prefer to use pgAdmin 3 but I get the following message when trying to connect to my database: 
"Warning:

The server you are connecting to is not a version that is supported by this release of pgAdmin III.

pgAdmin III may not function as expected.

Supported server versions are 8.4 to 9.3")

So I'm forced to use pgAdmin 4. However, when I restore (like I usually do on pgAdmin III) I get a 'successful' restore but no data is actually restored into the tables.

If I click on the details of the 'successful' restore I am presented with this:

"1. pg_restore: connecting to database for restore"

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Would you provide pgAdmin4 logs after running restore?

pgAdmin4 Log location:

**Linux:**

~/.pgadmin/pgAdmin4.log

~/.pgadmin/job_logs/

**Windows:**

%appdata%\pgAdmin\pgAdmin4.log

%appdata%\pgAdmin\job_logs\

Note: Do not close Success dialog in pgAdmin4 after restore otherwise once you acknowledge the success dialog, pgAdmin4 will delete respective job log files from "job_logs" directory & also delete "pgAdmin4.log" before running restore to trim unwanted logs.

Comment: 20161121135210265000,pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
20161121135210265000,pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING:
20161121135210265000,pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"
20161121135210265000,    Command was: SET row_security = off;
20161121135210265000,
20161121135210265000,WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1

Comment: The row_security configuration setting is new in 9.5, and that error indicates that you're restoring a database dump taken from a 9.5 database into an older version of PostgreSQL.

That combination is not supported, as new features can't work with old servers.

Comment: The backup is from a previous version of PostgreSQL (9.3) and I've upgraded to 9.5 - PGAdmin 4 supports 9.5 but it won't restore the tables like I was able to do on PGAdmin 3 on PostgreSQL 9.3.